# Different amount of rows after importing and counting

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, rows

I am importing 9136 rows from my csv file to mysqlWorkbench.After I imported them I used this to count them

But it shows me 54940 rows in my database.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_leads
```

also I counted the number of rows in 1 column with this command

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT Voronka)
```

but now it shows me the amount of 8426 rows. I am trying to understand is it because I lost some info while I was importing or I am counting wrong

Comment: Check your CSV file for end of line character for all lines especially at line 54940 and any possible data mismatch between data column types and data. You can use Notepad++ to open it as the your CSV does not have too many lines and then navigate: View -> show Symbols -> Show all characters.

Comment: Okay, I have 2 basic questions (avoiding assumptions here). 1) You want to know why you have more rows in your database after insertion, right? 2) Did you have data in table_leads previously, prior to the insert?

Comment: I also agree with @Cyrus comment, as I was about to make references to checking the CSV file.

Comment: yes I had but during inserting I picked to drop all tables and create them during importing so I don't think they are stacked all together.

Comment: @GeorgyFidarov: do you have constrains for that table? any possible duplicate rows?

Comment: Then, as @Cyrus mentioned, you may want to verify your CSV file, and make sure your data is clean.

Comment: @TinyHaitian Yes I. want to know where I am wrong first could be the problem with data maybe I am losing some of that after Importing or I am using wrong commands to count rows

Comment: @Cyrus Yes there is some duplicate rows but now a lot 2-3 copies of one. Should I clean that too

Comment: @TinyHaitian I cleaned my csv from all " ' this symbols before importing it. So I will try to find smth more but if I delete more I thing I will not be able no import that again

Comment: @TinyHaitian Also I there any command to see if data is stacked because I uploaded it multiple times in the same tables

Comment: @GeorgyFidarov: Yes remove the duplicates, or first import the file then look for duplicate rows: https://chartio.com/learn/databases/how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table/

Comment: @GeorgyFidarov I don't know your data well enough (or mysql for that matter - I'm a sql server person) to go into detail, but you should be able to query your table by a specific column, and a count of that column name, then have a group by option to see if you have any entry that has a count greater than one.

Comment: @Cyrus okay now I removed all duplicates and cleaned my csv. But now I got only 6824 rows out of 9136.

Comment: What happened after the upload of this now clean data? what happened when you did a select count(*)?

Comment: @GeorgyFidarov: I see you now get 8426 rows with having DISTINCT in your count, what's the count result if you run it without DISTINCT?  select COUNT(Voronka) FROM table_leads;

Comment: @TinyHaitian Now after I cleaned all ' and " it says this Unhandled exception: Could not determine delimiter

Check the log for more details.

Comment: @TinyHaitian Maybe the solution is to divide my data. because I have 9krows and 29 columns. and I am thinking to create multiple tables in MYSQLWB and then connect them all together and do the same with my other 9k rows data. This maybe be confusing but I hope in will work

Comment: @TinyHaitian now I can even Import even one column of data _(I am completely stacked

Comment: @GeorgyFidarov What command are you using to import the data from the CSV file?

Comment: @Cyrus I am importing it with the Wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cyrus I managed how to import all my data but I did that in the Mysql Model, but if I try to synchronize it happens this

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1115: Unknown character set: 'DEFAULT'
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Leads`.`amocrm_leads` (
          `Название сделки` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL,
          `Компания` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Основной контакт` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Компания контакта` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Ответственный` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Этап сделки` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Воронка` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Бюджет` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Дата создания` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Кем создана` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Дата изменения` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Кем изменена` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Теги сделки` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Ближайшая задача` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Дата закрытия` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Передано` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Номер FM` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Доход` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Другое` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `roistat` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Город` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Источник` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `utm_source` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `utm_medium` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `utm_campaign` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `utm_term` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `utm_content` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Переход с сайта` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Сайт` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `f30` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Ответственный врач` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Должность` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Рабочий email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Личный email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Другой email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `mail_list` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `work_phone1` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'DEFAULT' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `work_phone2` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `mobile_phone` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `fax` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `home_phone` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `another_phone` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Skype` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `ICQ` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Jabber` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Google Talk` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `MSN` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Другой IM` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Пользовательское соглашение` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Примечание 1` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Примечание 2` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Примечание 3` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Примечание 4` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE 'DEFAULT' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Примечание 5` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `id_fm_telmatch` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `temp_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `id_fm_count` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `Источник_` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `ind_filemaker_clear` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `match_found` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `ch_cannotfind` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `rea` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `relate_1` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`Название сделки`),
          CONSTRAINT `name_name`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Название сделки`)
            REFERENCES `Leads`.`data_table` (`name_name`)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8_bin

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: this is my first table